# Classify singularities of $f(z) = \frac{z^5}{1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I'm trying to classify the singularities of $f(z) = \frac{z^5}{1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4}$ and I was wondering if there was an easier way than going to the Laurent series expansion of the function around each point. I know (or I am pretty sure) that the singularities are at $\{e^\frac{2\pi}{5}, e^\frac{4\pi}{5}, e^\frac{6\pi}{5}, e^\frac{8\pi}{5}, \infty\}$. I know there's a Lemma that says

> $z_0$ is a removable singularity of $f \iff \lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)f(z) = 0$

So using this, I showed that the finite singularities weren't removable, but I didn't really know how to go any further.

Comment: Note that $1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4=\prod_{k=1}^4(z-\omega^k)$ where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/5}$ denotes a primitive 5th root of unity.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas yes, that's how I found the singularities. I guess I'm confused how that helps me show what kind of singularities they are. :/

Comment: Well, if they aren't removable singularities but they are isolated singularities, then they must be either poles (of some order) or essential singularities.  Do you know how to determine which these are?

Comment: We know that if $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}f(z) = \infty$, $z_0$ is a pole but how would I show what order the pole has?

Comment: @klamont15: The least positive integer $k$ for which $\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)^kf(z)$ is finite would be the order of the pole at $z=z_0$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas ohh thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$f(z) = \frac{z^5}{1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4} = \frac{z^5}{\frac{z^5-1}{z-1}} =  \frac{z^5(z-1)}{z^5-1} =\frac{(z^5-1)(z-1)+(z-1)}{z^5-1}= (z-1)\left(1 + \frac{1}{z^5-1}\right)$$